# Janusgraph - How to make case insensitive search with spaces - textContainsRegex not working with spaces

Tags: clojure, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I'm new to the Janusgraph Database. I have a requirement where I need to search the jansugraph with a query parameter.

**Example**

I have name with a value, ***"Janus Graph Engine"***. To search this, I'm using below predicate with regex expression.

`g.V().has("name", textContainsRegex(".*graph.*")`

Since, the above predicate is case-insensitive, I could able to get result even if I use query like below also

`g.V().has("name", textContainsRegex(".*Graph.*")`

But the problem is, when I wanted to put the search string including spaces I'm not able to get result.

`g.V().has("name", textContainsRegex(".*graph engine.*")`

Is there any way where we can search for text/string that should be case-insensitive as well as able to accept the spaces in between?

Because my requirement is when user types like this ***"nus gr"***, it should able to get the result since ***"nus gr"*** is the continuation in the entire string.

I have one more predicate called ***"textRegex"***, this accepts spaces but its case-sensitive.

Can you help me with this regard?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question from a while ago but I noticed it is not yet answered.

You can tell the `textRegex` function to ignore case as follows:

```
gremlin> g.addV('test').property('x','Janus Graph Engine')
==>v[4288]

gremlin> g.V().has("x", textRegex(".*(?i)nUs[ ]g.*"))
==>v[4288]
```